# iOS Simulator Accessibility Inspector Freeze

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5, accessibility-inspector

In the iOS simulator with XCode 5, opening the Accessibility Inspector freezes the simulator. There does not seem to be a way to exit the Accessibility Inspector.

Quitting and reopening the simulator, changing the hardware type, and restarting the computer all do not close the Accessibility Inspector.  Any other ideas for fixing the issue?

Comment: Good news. This is fixed in Xcode Version 5.0.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While not a complete fix for the accessibility inspector, clicking

iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings

will close the inspector.

The freeze will probably be fixed with the official release.

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed with the official release unfortunately :( (as of 9/25)

Answer (score 5):

This may not help depending on your project, but the Accessibility Inspector appears to still work in the iOS 6.1 Simulator.

Comment: Good tip. iOS 7.0 (463.9.4) crashes. Using the 6.1 simulator works just fine.